# cancel out box-sizing: border-box;

Tags: css

I need to add this styles to make my site responsive:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

but I need to cancel it out on a specific slider, as it messes it up. How can I do this just for the slider, which has HTML as follows:

```
 <div class="swiper-container s1">   
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide" >
              </div>
......................
```

Answer (score 0):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

```
.your-element {
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```